# Can I change the "Home" text in the menu?

Tags: pages, filters, title, customization, homepage

I’m pretty sure this can be done with a filter or some kind of find and replace, but I’m not sure how.

I have a page called “Home” like so:

[image: Screenshot]

When the link is displayed in my template it says “Home”. I’d like it to say “About Us”.

I want the user to know which page the homepage is in the Page Overview panel, but I’d like to be able to name it whatever I like in my template without displaying the word "Home". Any ideas?

Comment: Is this page assigned to be static home page via settings or something?

Comment: Rarst, yes the homepage is static...sorry for the late reply, just saw your comment...I found a solution, which I posted below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was really simple...In the admin panel I left the name as home, then I used conditional statements to change the name.

For the navigation I used:

```
<ul>
    <li <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>class="current_page_item"<?php } ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>">About Us</a></li>
    <?php $args = array("exclude" => "".page_name('Homepage').", "title_li"  => ""); wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

For the title I used:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <h2>About Us</h2>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this is how I was able to solve it!! Hope this helps someone :)